# Force dotnet CLI in English on a French Windows

Tags: .net-core

I'm French, and like to have the Windows UI in French, but all my dev tools in English.

The `dotnet` CLI tool displays its output in French, and I'd like to force it to English. Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE` environment variable to override the language used by the `dotnet`CLI:

```
> set DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en
> dotnet --help
…
[english content]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work (any more). Tested under dotnet 3.1.201 Windows 10 Version 1903 Build 18362.720

Comment: so much searching and this is so easy, thanks

Comment: It works with .NET 6 (preview 7)
with CMD use set DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en
with PS use $Env:DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE = "en"

Answer (score 12):

To set DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE environment variable please use:

- `DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en` in cmd.exe
- `$Env:DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE = "en"` in PowerShell

Answer (score 10):

**For unix-like system (Mac OS X, Linux)**

> set DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en

> dotnet --help

**For Windows**

> 1. setx DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE en

> 2. Goto "dotnet-install-directory\sdk\sdk-version" (For example C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102 in windows for dotnet version 3.1.102)

> 3. Delete folder of your language
>    for example, delete fr because your dotnet show French.
>    delete zh-Hans and zh-Hant if your dotnet show Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for RU-language too. 
`setx DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE en` - partially change the cli language. 
And `delete or rename folder of your language in "dotnet-install-directory\sdk\sdk-version"` that you can get via `dotnet --info` - changes finally the language to English.

Comment: deleting the folder of my language finally made the change.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers didn't work for me on MacOS with `zsh`.

What worked was

```
export DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en
```

but it's not enough, because as soon as you close your terminal this variable will be lost, so I had to add it to `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50217860/8090014),but it did not work

After that, i tried followings, it needs to work

1. Run the command `setx DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE en`
2. Go to location where dotnet is installed Go to
3. "dotnet-install-directory\sdk\sdk-version" (For example `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102` in windows for dotnet version 3.1.102)
4. Delete folder `zh-Hans` and zh-`Hant`

Answer (score 0):

on windows using bash

```bash
export DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en
```

you can run this command every time or add the command to ~/.bashrc file