# Turn off .NET localization in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, localization

I'm using Visual Studio Code on non-English Windows, developing Web API project in **.NET 6**. All the errors and warnings in VS Code are not in English, but in the system language (in my case it's Czech). When using **dotnet CLI** from built-in PowerShell terminal (e. g. `dotnet add package`), the the output is non-English as well.

When I open the same project in Visual Studio 2019, all errors and warnings are in English.

**How can I set VS Code to show .NET errors and warningns in English?**

Note: My Visual Studio Code interface is entirely English, I have no language pack installed.

EDIT: I have tried to set `set DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en` and CLI is now in English, but most of the errors and warnings remain localized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force dotnet CLI in English on a French Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217208/force-dotnet-cli-in-english-on-a-french-windows)

Comment: @Ascendise Thank you, it helps partially. CLI is now in English, most of the errors and warnings still remain localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is a [known issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2513) with Omnisharp.

The recommended workaround is to navigate to your Omnisharp directory. You can find the path by looking at the Omnisharp logs.

```
OmniSharp server started.
    Path: C:\Users\Gabriel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.1\.omnisharp\1.32.5\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 144684
```

Inside the folder, look for the directory with the name for your locale. (Czech should be cs-CZ).

Inside the 'cs-CZ' folder, delete all DLLs that start with `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`

Now the language of the errors and warnings should fall back to english.

Comment: It works! Thank you. but unfortunately the dlls must be manually deleted each time the C# plugin is updated by VS Code.

Comment: The exact folder location depends on the version of the C# extension and .NET installed – in my case it was `C:\Users\Gabriel\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.1-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.39.2-net6.0\cs`